# R: How I can encode in twitteR package?

Tags: r, twitter, text-mining

I have been struggling with encoding in twitteR.
The code below is the one I tried.

```
query <- list()
query <- c(query, "xxx")
query <- c(query, "xxx2")
for(i in 1:length(query)){
result<-searchTwitter(query[i],n=500, resultType ="recent",lang="en")
seo_tweets <- c(tweets,result)
seo_tweets <- unique(tweets)
}
```

But it ended up fetching the garbage data such as: **Motor at #IAA2017 \xed��\xed�� https://t.c.**
I have tried this code as well, but it did not work at all.

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")
```

How can I solve this issue? Here's sessioninfo

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] wordcloud_2.5      RColorBrewer_1.1-2 tm_0.7-1           NLP_0.1-11         stringr_1.2.0      h2o_3.10.5.3       rvest_0.3.2
 [8] xml2_1.1.1         ggmap_2.6.1        ggplot2_2.2.1      twitteR_1.1.8      base64enc_0.1-3    ROAuth_0.9.6       ROCR_1.0-7
[15] gplots_3.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtools_3.5.0       slam_0.1-40        reshape2_1.4.2     lattice_0.20-35    colorspace_1.3-2   rlang_0.1.1        withr_2.0.0
 [8] DBI_0.7            selectr_0.3-1      sp_1.2-5           bit64_0.9-7        jpeg_0.1-8         plyr_1.8.4         munsell_0.4.3
[15] gtable_0.2.0       devtools_1.13.3    caTools_1.17.1     RgoogleMaps_1.4.1  mapproj_1.2-5      memoise_1.1.0      curl_2.8.1
[22] parallel_3.4.1     proto_1.0.0        Rcpp_0.12.12       KernSmooth_2.23-15 geosphere_1.5-5    openssl_0.9.6      scales_0.4.1
[29] gdata_2.18.0       jsonlite_1.5       bit_1.1-12         rjson_0.2.15       png_0.1-7          digest_0.6.12      stringi_1.1.5
[36] grid_3.4.1         tools_3.4.1        bitops_1.0-6       magrittr_1.5       maps_3.2.0         lazyeval_0.2.0     RCurl_1.95-4.8
[43] tibble_1.3.3       httr_1.3.1         R6_2.2.2           git2r_0.19.0       compiler_3.4.1

Thank you.

Comment: I have tried to encode the data after fetching from twitter, but here is the thing. > guess_encoding(seo_tweets)
     encoding language confidence
1  ISO-8859-1       en       0.36
2  ISO-8859-2       cs       0.23
3       UTF-8                0.15
4    UTF-16BE                0.10
5    UTF-16LE                0.10
6   Shift_JIS       ja       0.10
7     GB18030       zh       0.10
8      EUC-JP       ja       0.10
9      EUC-KR       ko       0.10
10       Big5       zh       0.10

Comment: As you can see, I can not decide which encoding should be applied.